# Why is the initializer of for loop enclosed in square brackets?

Tags: for-loop, square-bracket

```
for (let i=0; i<select.options.length; i++) {
    if(selectObject.options[i].selected) {
        numberSelected++
    }
}
```

Is it necesarry to put a square brackets to access the initializer in the loop?

Comment: No. but you are using `i` as index of `options` which necessitates the square brackets

Comment: When writing a question please state what you expect the code to do. Please also add the programming language relevant in the tags.

Comment: Thanks man! Sorry for i didnt put a pl, im new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Cleaner and less error-prone code (just like you ask) exists.

```
const optionsIterator = select.options.values();

for (const oneOption of optionsIterator) {
    if(oneOption.selected) {
        numberSelected ++
    }
}
```